# KeyError 'href' - Python / Selenium / Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm running into an issue when web-scraping a large web page, my scrape works fine for the first 30 href links however runs into a KeyError: 'href' at around 25% into the page contents.

The elements remain the same for the entire web page i.e there is no difference between the last scraped element and the next element that stops the script. Is this caused by the driver not loading the entire web page in time for the scrape to complete or only partially loading the web page ?

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from random import randint


chromedriver_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
service = Service(chromedriver_path)
options = Options()

# options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)



url = 'https://hackerone.com/bug-bounty-programs'


driver.get(url)
sleep(randint(15,20))
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
# driver.quit()
links = soup.find_all("a")
for link in links:
    print(link['href'])
```

[image: Heres a screenshot of the error]

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for selenium if wishing to retrieve the bounty links. That seems more desirable than grabbing all links off the page. It also removes the duplicates you get with scraping all links.

Simply use the queryString construct that returns bounties as json. You can update the urls to include the protocol and domain.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

data = requests.get('https://hackerone.com/programs/search?query=bounties:yes&sort=name:ascending&limit=1000').json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['results'])
df['url'] = 'https://hackerone.com' + df['url']
print(df.head())
```